# Can I assert that a Wi-Fi AP with a higher "quality" will be better in most cases?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

I have an application on Raspberry Pi that needs to determine which available Wi-Fi access point to use, with their statistics collected by `iwlib` beforehand.

`iwlib` or `iwlist` has three indicies for each Wi-Fi access point: "quality", "signal level", and "noise level". By saying a Wi-Fi access point is "good", I am talking about a high success rate in transmission.

My question is: Is it safe to assume that one access point with a higher "quality" is mostly likely to be better than one with a lower "quality" value?

Answer (score 1):

The `quality` is dependent on the chipset of your device and its driver.  Many will show a value of zero for quality while working fine.  Even on those that do show a `quality` value, the algorithm for this value isn't standardised therefore you cannot compare between different chipsets.

Even when using one adapter (as in your case) the fact that the calculations used to work out this `quality` value differ between hardware/drivers means that not all devices would give the same results for your APs.  One adapter may calculate AP A's quality to be higher than AP B's, while another adapter may calculate B's to be higher than A's.

From `man iwconfig`:

> **Link quality**
>   Overall quality of the link. May be based on the level of contention or interference, the bit or frame error rate, how good the received signal is, some timing synchronisation, or other hardware metric. This is an aggregate value, and depends totally on the driver and hardware.

`quality` is therfore of no real use and cannot be relied upon.